# Is dbSet.Include pointless if called after dbSet is called?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, entity-framework, linq

Let's say I have a method like so:

```
public DbSet<Ingredient> GetIngredients(int limit = 0)
        {
            return db.Ingredients;
        }
```

So that in my Controller, I can make a call like this:

```
var ingredients = GetIngredients()
.Include(i => i.AspNetUser)
.Include(i => i.AspNetUser1)
.Include(i => i.Ingredient_Category)
.Include(i => i.Measurement_Unit);
```

Would it be pointless or slow because the `GetIngredients()` call is going to load everything anyway?

If so, is there a way I can get `GetIngredients()` to use various includes as params?

Worst case scenario I can make a load of different methods in the repository for each scenario (or should I just be doing that anyway? It feels like the controller should be saying what the view wants... or is DbSet unique to EF and I should only be returning IEnumarables from my repository?)

Many Thanks

Comment: You need to clarify your question,  You use includes if your are 1. Not doing lazy loading, 2. Are doing Lazy Loading but you would rather request everything in a single query.  Now if you including multiple includes with many to many relationship, your probably going to want to load those seperately to avoid carstesian production.    Your question is still unclear though do you want to do you includes seperately because you want to apply filtering to what is included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would it be pointless or slow because the GetIngredients() call is
>   going to load everything anyway?

No, your query is not going to be executed until you consult it (eg, via foreach) or calling `ToList` or `ToArray` extenstion methods

> Is there a way I can get GetIngredients() to use various includes as
>   params?

```
public IQueryable<Ingredient> GetIngredients(List<Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>> includes = null)
{
     IQueryable<TEntity> query = db.Ingredients;

     if (includes != null)
     {
         query = includes.Aggregate(query, (current, include) => current.Include(include));
     }
     return query;
}
```

About your last concern, you should fetch the data from your DB before your `DbContext` being disposed. So if you're calling this method from your controller to pass the result as parameter to your view then change the return type an `IEnumerable<Ingredient>` and call `ToList` at the end of your method `query.ToList();` to make sure you're executing your query before your pass the result to your view.

Comment: "No, your query is not going to be executed until you consult it (eg, via foreach) or calling ToList or ToArray extenstion methods" is exactly what I needed to know!